# How to include file multiple times using anchor tag

Tags: php, html

I have some inputs that I need to regenerate every time the user hits `+add experience` link. these are the inputs inside the form:

```
<label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="company-name">
<label for="job-title">Job Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-title">
```

and this is the anchor tag which is supposed to generate the previous html every time when clicked:

```
<a href="test.php">+ Add Experience</a>
```

so if user clicked `+add experience` 3 times , the html should be repeated 3 times in same page

I don't know if I should use a function or include the html in a new file, and how to do that!!
please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: unless you want the page to reload, that will require JavaScript

Comment: my JavaScript knowledge is weak, isn't there any other solution with out javascript? @Dagon

Comment: you can do it with php. but each click would reload the page

Comment: please can you tell me how to do it with php? @Dagon

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your JavaScript knowledge is a bit weak, no problem! It's not too difficult, take a look at this example below. This is how it is properly done is JavaScript. It's inefficient to try this 100% in PhP.

```js
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
                // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "member" + i;
                container.appendChild(input);
                // Append a line break 
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head
<body>
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <div id="container"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This example was supplied by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/851811/xavi-l%c3%b3pez @xavi-lópez

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches you can take:

1. Use a js function to generate the html dynamically, and append it to the DOM.
2. Store a hidden html template with the necessary inputs in the original html file. When clicking the add button, use the Node.cloneNode() on the hidden template and append the newly cloned node to the DOM. (Be sure to update the id attribute on the element you cloned, we don't want duplicate ids).
3. Request the html template from the server, and append the response to the DOM. This can be done via jquery/ajax. (i.e. $.load(url, data,complete) http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Could you comment on why this answer was not useful?

Comment: thanks for your respond , but my javascript knowledge is weak !

Comment: I would highly suggest getting up to speed with JavaScript, as this is the cornerstone of interactive web applications.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it , and thanks again for your help :)